# Multiple output from modules in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm provisioning multiple EC2 instances (in this case 2) using the Terraform Module called `ec2-instance`. In the output I want to receive IDs of provisioned EC2 instances.

```
locals {
  app = {
    instance1 = {
      name = "instance1"
      az = "eu-west-1a"
    }
    instance2 = {
      name = "instance2"
      az = "eu-west-1c"
    }
  }
}

module "ec2-instance" {
  for_each = local.app
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/ec2-instance/aws"
  version = "5.5.0"
  name = each.value.name
  availability_zone = each.value.az
}

output "ids_of_instances" {
   value = module.ec2-instance[*].id
 }
```

I'm getting an error:

> Error: Unsupported attribute
> │
> │   on main.tf line 96, in output "ids_of_instances":
> │   96:   value = module.ec2-instance[*].id
> │
> │ This object does not have an attribute named "id".

Obviously I can try to use multiple outputs blocks like:

```
output "instance1" { 
  value = module.ec2-instance["instance1"].id
}

output "instance1" { 
  value = module.ec2-instance["instance2"].id
}
```

but the goal is to get this output from 1 single block. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `for_each` will create a map of your modules. The [documentation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/splat) for the splat expression says that you should use a [for expression](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/for) with maps, instead of a splat expression.

I'm not at a place where I can test this right now, I believe that would look like this:

```
output "ids_of_instances" {
    value = [for instance in module.ec2-instance : instance.id]
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. Indeed for loop solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since the module is created with `for_each`, you can use the built-in [`values` function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/values) to get all the values of the outputs you want:

```
output "ids_of_instances" {
   value = values(module.ec2-instance)[*].id
 }
```